# How to sync directories on different webservers? Cron-Job?

Tags: cron, cdn

I am plannig to implement a CDN and need to sync directories on my main domain with the directories on the CDN. I thought that maybe a cron-job would do the trick but i dont know how.

Comment: I'd highly advise using a CDN service instead of trying to implement it

Comment: I want to use a CDN service but to keep the JS and CSS files updated i have to manually copy them into the CDN directory. Thats why i am looking for an automated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not the only way to keep folders in sync, I think, rsync may be the most basic approach. Type

```
 crontab -e
```

This will open cron table editor for the current user. Press "a" to switch into text append mode and type something like

```
 0 4 */3 * *  /home/me/run-my-rsync.sh >> /home/me/mysync.log
```

then press ESC : x to close (vi is a great editor worth to learn). This will run your bash script containing rsync commands at 4:00 every third day.

`/home/me/run-my-rsync.sh` must be an existing file containing rsync commands. Here, also, it is possible to have a very complex script, the most basic would probably  be

```
 #!/bin/bash
 rsync -avz remote.machine.com:cdn /home/me/cdn
```

This would recursively transfer all new or changed files from the directory /home/me/cdn on the remote.machine.com into the /home/me/cdn directory on the local  machine. Only the changed files will be transferred. You bash file must be executable to run on cron (`chmod +x /home/me/run-my-rsync.sh`).

Surely, this can only work if the ssh daemon (sshd) is running on the remote machine and you have access rights for it. In order rsync to work automatically, you need to setup the proper authentication using SSH keys as described [here](http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html), for instance.

I would suggest first to create accounts on both machines, install sshd, check if the trivial login works, then try manually if your rsync commands work (the password will be asked), then configure to use ssh keys rather than password and at the end try to create the cron job.